# En français, est-ce que « de très bons amis » peut impliquer un sous-entendu sexuel ?

Tags: sens, expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

En anglais, quand quelqu’un dit « Oh, they’re very good friends! » c’est tout à fait normal mais il y a des situations où on peut le dire pour insinuer qu’il y a une relation sexuelle entre deux personnes.

Est-ce que ça peut avoir le même sens en français ?

Comment: Tangentially, I have seen "ami(e)" used by itself in reference to a lover, and "amitié particulière" and its derivatives can have that connotation (but not always). It's highly contextual though.

Answer (score 3):

Oui mais je vois plus souvent une exagération/répétition utilisée quand tel est le cas;

> de très **très** bons amis

Comment: Peux-tu préciser quel variante(s) du français tu parles ? C'est le genre de chose qui pourrait bien être différent d'un pays, d'une région ou d'une culture à l'autre.

Comment: @Gilles fr-ca :) L'expression semblent plus utilisée depuis qu'ici, je ne sais pas si en France tel est le cas, mais depuis que le concept de friendzone existe et que les couples ne veuille plus s'afficher comme couple facilement. Une expression en example; "Cela fait deux ans qu'ils habitent ensemble, ont peut dire qu'ils sont de très très bons amis même s'il ne sont pas encore en couple."

Answer (score 0):

*C'est des très bons amis* pour moi n'a pas de connotation sexuelle.  Par contre *une bonne copine*, dit par un garçon, peut vouloir dire *a fuck buddy*.  Ça devrait marcher dans l'autre sens dit par une fille à propos d'un garçon (*un bon copain*), mais je n'en suis pas sûr.  A vérifier auprès des locutrices natives du français.

Comment: est-ce que ça marcherait avec une fille qui dit « une bonne copine » ou un mec qui dit « un bon copain » ? ou c’est plutôt pour les hétérosexuels ?

Comment: Il faudrait vérifier l'usage chez les gays et les lesbiennes.  Le rapport à ce type de relations sexuelles varie peut-être entre l'hétérosexualité et l'homosexualité et entre l'homosexualité masculine et l'homosexualité féminine.  Ma remarque vaut pour un homme qui dirait ça à propos d'une femme.  Je précise que "bonne copine" n'est pas péjoratif.

Comment: d’acccord, c’est noté ! merci beaucoup

Comment: Peux-tu préciser quel variante(s) du français tu parles ? C'est le genre de chose qui pourrait bien être différent d'un pays, d'une région ou d'une culture à l'autre.

Comment: @Gilles  Le français français.

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour,

Je ne vois aucune connotation sexuelle dans cette expression ! Des amis restent des amis !
Personnellement, j'ai de très bonnes amies et il n'y a rien de sexuel dans notre relation !

Comment: c’est pas littéralement ça que je voulais dire, haha. c’est juste qu’en anglais c’est POSSIBLE que « very good friends » peut avoir une connotation sexuelle selon le contexte (un contexte de plaisanterie par exemple). moi aussi j’ai de très bons amis avec aucun élément sexuel là-dedans !